How should Psalm 5:1 הֲגִֽיגִי׃ best be translated
(English Standard Version) - Give ear to my words, O Lord;
consider my groaning.
(New International Version) - Listen to my words, Lord,
consider my lament.
(New King James Version) - Give ear to my words, O Lord, Consider my meditation.
(New American Standard Bible) - Listen to my words, Lord,
Consider my sighing.
I notice that the Hebrew word used here comes from hagig meaning: a whisper, musing, murmuring.
There is a wide birth of translations.
What is the most appropriate translation of הֲגִֽיגִי׃ in Psalm 5:1

Is he groaning?
Is he lamenting?
Is he meditating?
Is he sighing?

Or should it be something like whispering, musing, or murmuring?
Does it make more sense to assume that he is expressing his thoughts quietly or silently (inwardly)?

הָגִיג only occurs in twice in the Hebrew Old Testament (Tanakh, MT), Psalms 5:1; 39:3 (5:2; 39:3 in the Hebrew text).  Both times it has the 1st person singular suffice meaning my.  The Lexicons show the variations in the translations.

[הָגִיג S1901 TWOT466a GK2052] n.m. murmuring (Che), whisper, musing (on form cf. Ba 136)—only sf. הֲגִיגִי 1. ψ 5:2 בִּינָה ה׳ understand my murmuring (whispering, faint utterance), addressed to י׳. 2. ψ 39:4 בַּהֲגִיגִי in my musing i.e. while I was musing.
--
Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). In Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon (p. 211). Clarendon Press.


*הָגִיג: הגג; Syr. pl. hgēgē, Mnd. (MdD 130b) hgaga illusions: הֲגִיגִי: sighing (in prayer, στεναγμὸς ἀλάλητος Rom 826) Ps 5:2 39:4. †
--
Koehler, L., Baumgartner, W., Richardson, M. E. J., & Stamm, J. J. (1994–2000). In The Hebrew and Aramaic lexicon of the Old Testament (electronic ed., p. 238). E.J. Brill.

Perhaps Paul was thinking of these passages in Rom. 8:26, but there isn't a connection in the Greek of the Septuagint (LXX) and Rom. 8:28. Perhaps the best we can do is look at the similarity in the mean of the various translations.

+1. This is a time that I feel that the English translations and the given Greek meaning are rather different. I don't even understand how the NIV got lament.

We find a similar presentation in Mark 7:34, put in different phraseology  from version to version.
Contemporary English Version:
Jesus looked up toward heaven, and with a groan he said, "Effatha!" which means "Open up!"
Douay-Rheims Bible:
And looking up to heaven, he groaned, and said to him: Ephpheta, which is, Be thou opened.
English Revised Version:
and looking up to heaven, he sighed, and saith unto him, Ephphatha, that is, Be opened.
See that Jesus is healing a deaf man . He has to be audible to  those around and loud enough for the person who can't hear  anything let alone a whisper, till healed . The deaf man
can do  lip-reading and understand that Jesus  is saying something aloud on his behalf .
As for Psalm 5:1, the psalmist wants to tell the Lord that he has been praying aloud with fully expressed emotions  and wonders  from within if he has not been loud enough to be heard. Compare this with the silent prayer of Hannah in 1 Samuel 1.Only her lips move, and she is taken for drunk by the Priest.  After all, there is no predetermined
disposition - either physical or mental-  of prayer. Jesus instructed  the disciples to pray in a closed room, but he also prayed loudly on the Cross.
Now, to directly answer the question: If Mark 7: 34 is to be treated as a sequel, Psalm 5:1 is best translated with the expression: groans or sighs  . And, that is loud and clear !

But, open is פתוח. A different word.

This psalm follows the typical pattern of a lament. It begins with a complaint - an expression of distress - and moves to  plead for God's help. Finally it ends in confidence and praise.
The above explains why NIV says "Lord, consider my lament." For NIV, it is not the immediate cry/groan/sigh, but the entire psalm that the poet implores God to hear. A similar approach may be intended in the KJV version: the editors have decided that the whole psalm is meant, not the immediate cry.
Taking the interpretation more immediately, whether the psalmist is "groaning" or "sighing" isn't exactly a distinction without a difference, but either of the two English words will suffice.
Conclusion: If the verse refers to the entire psalm, then either "lament" or "meditation" is appropriate, although "lament" is better since this captures the fact the poet expresses distress. If the verse is understood as referring to the psalmist's immediate communication with God, then either sighing or groaning is appropriate.
